# Refreshing a DataGrid within a datatemplate in order to update the bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, datatemplate

The properties in the (below) DataGrid are not Observable so they do not get updated in the view automatically. Keeping them as not observable is intentional. The underlying model data does get updated at some point and, when it does, I would rather have the user do a manual "Refresh" from a button to update the datagrid view. I've attached a command to the Refresh button executing

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Units).Refresh();
```

in the view model. This seems to update the underlying view data but it doesn't "refresh" the UI for the datagrid. However, if I click anywhere on the datagrid after the refresh button has been pushed, the datagrid redraws and the data is updated in the view. I need a means to manually trigger a datagrid refresh when the button is pushed. Perhaps because the datagrid is within a datatemplate? Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks

```
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" TabContent.IsCached="True">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabContent.Template>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Margin="5">
                        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">                            
                            <WrapPanel>                                                                                   
                                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.Refresh, ElementName=Window}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Refresh</Button>
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
                                <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontWeight="Bold">Items</Label>
                                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Key}" Header="Name"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Value"/>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.RV}" Header="RV"/>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, GUI changes are propagated to source properties by bindings, but those properties are not observable and thus you expect other bindings not to update. If so, then you have wrong expectations.

Comment: Bindings for changing and listening to model properties primarily use the PropertyDescriptor mechanism. If one of the bindings changes the value of a property, then all bindings to that property will receive a change notification, regardless of whether the notification is implemented via INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged. This notification will only matter when updating the property directly in Sharpe's code, i.e. without using the PropertyDescriptor.